# Lazy fields always loaded

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have classes with a many-to-one relationship. When I query for them using Criteria.list, the lazy fields are populated.

```
public class SE {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mSe")
    private List<RS> mRs;
}

public class RS {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "my_join_id")
    private SE mSe;
}
```

...

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SE.class);    
List<SE> myObjects = criteria.list();

// SE objects have lazy list populated. why?
```

How do I prevent the lazy fields from being loaded?

Comment: How do you know they are populated? And, what is the query when you run `criteria.list()` ?

Comment: If you run a query, i.e fetch data, shouldn't they be populated?

Comment: The criertia is as shown in the post. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding lazy loading. I assumed the fields wouldn't be loaded unless I explicilty loaded them by using an accessor while the transaction was still happening.I can tell the lazy list is loaded by looking at teh debugger after the trasnaction has ended.

Comment: When looking in the debugger that will trigger the loading. Also are you sure the transaction stopped and the session is closed? The fact that the tx ended doesn't mean (necessarily ) that the session is closed, especially when using something like an open session in view pattern.

Comment: The list is a proxy. As soon as you try to access it, by debugger or in the code, proxy will trigger a query and load the list content.

Comment: The query is being executed by a spring MVC controller. THe method that the controller calls is annotated with a spring @Transactional scope.

Comment: The only way you can make sure they are not populated, is by looking at the query when loading the `SE` object. If it's lazy, query shouldn't have a join to `RS` table.

Comment: So I think what's happening is that the debugger, or int he case of not using the debugger, Jackson which tried to serialize the list, is causing the records to be populated.

Comment: That's what @M. Deinum told you, yes.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it is populated?

If you are looking with your debugger, it is a normal behavior because the debuger do a lot of stuff and most of the time call the getter to have a string representation of the instance. Since the getter is called, the lazy loading is triggered.

What you can do to ensure it is really lazy loaded is remove your `@Transactional` annotation, and you should have an error when rying to access `SE` in the debugger.